# Custom Delegate does not update UI in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, user-interface, delegates

I write a custom delegate listening for the changes of microphone audio data and it's length. The main Controller plot the audio wave when the data changes in the delegate method. The result is the microphone data and length do change in the mainController, but the plot does not display.

Declaration of Delegate in .h:

```
@class SXDetectAlgorithm;

@protocol SXDetectAlgorithmDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)detectAlgorihtm:(SXDetectAlgorithm *)detectAlgorihtm outputBufferValue:(float *)micBuffer withBufferSize:(UInt32)bufferSize;

@end

@interface SXDetectAlgorithm : NSObject <EZMicrophoneDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SXDetectAlgorithmDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Implement Delegate in .m:

```
// Use third party API to get microphone data
-(void)    microphone:(EZMicrophone *)microphone
     hasAudioReceived:(float **)buffer
       withBufferSize:(UInt32)bufferSize
 withNumberOfChannels:(UInt32)numberOfChannels {

 // Process the microphone data and then feed to "micBuffer"
 ...
 ...
 ...

 // Back to the main thread to respond delegate
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    SXMainController *mainController = [[SXMainController alloc] init];
    self.delegate = mainController;
    [self.delegate detectAlgorihtm:self outputBufferValue:micBuffer withBufferSize:bufferSize];
});
```

Declare Delegate in mainController.h:

```
@interface SXMainController () <SXDetectAlgorithmDelegate> 

@property (nonatomic, strong) SXDetectAlgorithm *detectAlgorithm;

@end
```

Use Delegate to plot wave in mainController.m:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{

    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        self.detectAlgorithm = [[SXDetectAlgorithm alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)detectAlgorihtm:(SXDetectAlgorithm *)detectAlgorihtm
      outputBufferValue:(float *)lpfout
         withBufferSize:(UInt32)bufferSize {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    // Plot method...
    // Use a button to test if it can display
    UIButton *testButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
    testButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:testButton];
    });  
}
```

My problem is even if I return on the main thread to plot wave or display a button, UI of the mianController does not update at all. I am wondering for a long time where the problem is. Can some one give me advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SXMainController *mainController = [[SXMainController alloc] init];
self.delegate = mainController;
[self.delegate detectAlgorihtm:self outputBufferValue:micBuffer withBufferSize:bufferSize];
```

This code creates a new viewController every time you receive audio data, which is most likely not what you're trying to achieve.

What you probably want to do is set your viewController as the delegate after you create you Detection object, so:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{

if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
    self.detectAlgorithm = [[SXDetectAlgorithm alloc] init];
    self.detectAlgorithm = self;
}
return self;
}
```

And just call

```
self.delegate detectAlgorihtm:self outputBufferValue:micBuffer withBufferSize:bufferSize];
```

from the other object

Answer (score 2):

The delegate calling class is initiated but it is not set to where the delegate method is appearing.

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{

    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        self.detectAlgorithm = [[SXDetectAlgorithm alloc] init];
        [self.detectAlgorithm setDelegate:self];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and

```
 // Back to the main thread to respond delegate
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.delegate detectAlgorihtm:self outputBufferValue:micBuffer withBufferSize:bufferSize];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the required data to display, and still its not getting displayed, then It means, somehow your display area is getting reinitialised somehow, due to which the data gets reset and dosen't display anything.